# PLSQL UPDATE statement in LOOP takes forever

Tags: oracle, plsql

If I execute

```
UPDATE person 
SET CUSTOM2 = TIMESTAMP_DIFF(SYSTIMESTAMP,TO_TIMESTAMP (CUSTOM1, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF')) 
WHERE  person.id = 'p01';
```

it updates fine but if I execute update statement inside the loop it hangs forever

```
DECLARE
   
    TYPE person_ids_t IS table of person.id%type index by PLS_INTEGER;
    ids_collection person_ids_t;
    CURSOR cur  IS  select id from person where CUSTOM1 is not null;
   
BEGIN   
    OPEN cur;   
   
--    LOOP   
        FETCH cur   BULK COLLECT INTO ids_collection   LIMIT 10;   
--        EXIT WHEN ids_collection.COUNT = 0;   
   
        FORALL idx IN 1 .. ids_collection.COUNT
            UPDATE person 
            SET CUSTOM2 = TIMESTAMP_DIFF(SYSTIMESTAMP,TO_TIMESTAMP (CUSTOM1, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF')) 
            WHERE  person.id = ids_collection(idx);
   
      COMMIT;   
--   END LOOP;  
   CLOSE cur;  
END;
```

When I execute above block, ScriptRunner hangs forever and I have to force quit.
Not sure why.

even changing the script to

```
set SERVEROUTPUT ON;
DECLARE
    c_id person.id%type;
    CURSOR cur  IS  select id from person where CUSTOM1 is not nul;
    
    vcount integer :=0;
   
BEGIN   
    OPEN cur;   
   
    LOOP 
        FETCH cur into c_id;
        EXIT WHEN cur%notfound; 
 
   
       
--        UPDATE person 
--        SET CUSTOM2 = TIMESTAMP_DIFF(SYSTIMESTAMP,TO_TIMESTAMP (CUSTOM1, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF')) 
--        WHERE  person.id = c_id;
        
        dbms_output.put_line('c_id: ' || c_id); 
        
        vcount := vcount + 1;
        IF vcount = 1 THEN
            EXIT;
        END IF; 
   END LOOP;  
   CLOSE cur;  
   
   dbms_output.put_line('vcount: ' || vcount); 
   
END;
/
```

If I execute this it prints
c_id: p01
vcount: 1

but when I uncomment the update statement it hangs forever

Comment: is your person.id column indexed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that previous update wasn't committed and it keeps those rows **locked** so you're just waiting for commit (or rollback).

Anyway: why would you use an option which is suboptimal? As you've already seen, an ordinary `UPDATE` does the job just fine. Doing it in a loop is updating row-by-row which promises to be slow-by-slow. If I were you, I wouldn't bother.

---

If you want to find who's blocking who, there are Oracle dictionary views you may query. There are also numerous scripts available on the Internet, have a look. Or, if you use some GUI - like TOAD, which offers the "Schema Browser" that lets you easily see that info - use it.

Meanwhile, just for example, there's the `TEST` table in Scott's schema; I updated it in one session as:

```
SQL> update test set sal = 2000 where empno = 7369;

1 row updated.

SQL>
```

Then I connected to another session (also as Scott) and ran

```
SQL> update test set sal = 3000;
```

and - nothing happened. It *hangs*. So I connected as SYS (which has access to all dictionary views; if you have some other user with appropriate privileges, use it) and queried the database as:

```
SQL> select
  2     (select username from v$session where sid = a.sid) blocker,
  3     --
  4     a.sid,
  5     ' is blocking ',
  6     --
  7     (select username from v$session where sid = b.sid) blockee,
  8     --
  9     b.sid
 10  from v$lock a join v$lock b on a.id1 = b.id1 and a.id2 = b.id2
 11  where a.block = 1
 12    and b.request > 0;

BLOCKER                SID 'ISBLOCKING'  BLOCKEE                SID
--------------- ---------- ------------- --------------- ----------
SCOTT                  141  is blocking  SCOTT                   92

SQL>
```

So, yes - my session 141 is blocking my another session 92. I should commit (or rollback) in session 141 to let session 92 proceed.

Comment: There is a purpose of doing so. is there a way I could find out which rows are locked and how can I release them.

Comment: I added some more info; have a look, please.

Comment: Thank you, because I already had to force quit the SQL developer tools, is there any threshold on a waiting period, or should I inform DBA to kill it :)

Comment: Well, Oracle *will* eventually kill it, sooner or later (say, half an hour or so); I'd call DBA and ask them to assist.